# Como recorrer este array

Tags: php, array, wordpress

Tengo este array, de esta forma digamos poniendo le el `offset` que es el `0`.

Manualmente funciona lo que yo quiero es que me devuelva todos los valores de ese `array` sin que yo le ponga el `offset`

```
$data_array[$section_key][$section_data_key][$block_key]['content_block_images'] = brc_make_link_relative_if_local(wp_get_attachment_url( $data_array[$section_key][$section_data_key][$block_key]['content_block_images']['0']['image'] ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  // Función recursiva que recorre un array tantos elementos y dimensiones contenga
function recorrer_array_recursivo($array)
{
  foreach($array as $value)
  {
    // Si es un array, invoco de nuevo la función
    if(is_array($value))
    {
      recorrer_array_recursivo($value);
    }else{

    // Si no, imprimo el valor. Aquí puedes almacenar la info en vez de imprimir. 
      echo $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Para pruebas:

```
$a = array( array( array( array(1)), 2, 3 ), array( 4, 5, 6), 7, 8);


recorrer_array_recursivo($a);
```

Ejecuta esta función con tu array y comentas. Saludos.

Comment: No funciona :( intente pero nada

Comment: Había un error, lo corregí. Veo que el array que pones invoca a una función de wordpress, entonces si devuelve un array o un valor, aún así debería poder funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro de entender bien lo que necesitas, pero supongamos que:

> Lo que quieres, es asingar es en la posición `$data_array[$section_key][$section_data_key][$block_key]['content_block_images']`, todos los links a las imagenes dentro de si.

Entonces podrías hacer esto:

```
    // Hacemos uso de asignación por referencia
    $images = &$data_array[$section_key][$section_data_key][$block_key]['content_block_images'];
    $links = '';

    // Recorremos el arreglo de imagenes
    foreach($images as $info) {
      // Obtenemos los links
      $links .= brc_make_link_relative_if_local(wp_get_attachment_url( $info['image']));
    }
    // Sobre escribimos el valor
    $images = $links;
```

[¿Qué hacen las referencias?](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatdo.php)